# jsf2 ViewScoped bean initialization

Tags: jsf-2, intellij-idea, view-scope

I'm new to jsf technology and I'm trying to understand when and how the **ViewScoped** jsf bean is initialized.

I have a sample app with 2 beans

### ApplicationScopedBean.java

```java
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationScopedBean implements Serializable {
    private int incrementedCounter =0;

    public int getIncrementedCounter() {
        incrementedCounter += 1;
        return incrementedCounter;
    }
}
```

### ViewScopedBean.java

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewScopedBean implements Serializable {
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{applicationScopedBean}")
    private ApplicationScopedBean applicationScopedBean;

    private int reincarnationNumber;

    private int accessCounter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        accessCounter = 0;
        reincarnationNumber = applicationScopedBean.getIncrementedCounter();
        System.out.println("Initializing viewScoped stateManager with reincarnationNumber value = " + String.valueOf(reincarnationNumber));
    }

    public void noAction() {
        //do nothing
    }

    public int getReincarnationNumber() {
        return reincarnationNumber;
    }
    public int getAccessCounter() {
        accessCounter += 1;
        return accessCounter;
    }

    public ApplicationScopedBean getApplicationScopedBean() {
        return applicationScopedBean;
    }
    public void setApplicationScopedBean(ApplicationScopedBean applicationScopedBean) {
        this.applicationScopedBean = applicationScopedBean;
    }
}
```

ApplicationScoped bean is created only once for the application launch.
Every time ViewScoped bean is being created, the `reincarnationNumber` is being increased by 1.

I also have a simple jsf page to display these values:

### index.xhtml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>View Scoped bean test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>    
        <p>ViewScoped bean reincarnation is <h:outputText value="#{viewScopedBean.reincarnationNumber}"/></p>
        <p>ViewScoped bean access counter is <h:outputText value="#{viewScopedBean.accessCounter}"/></p>

        <h:commandButton type="submit" value="no action" action="#{viewScopedBean.noAction()}"/>
        <h:commandButton type="submit" value="reload this page" action="index"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

---

### The problem:

When I launch the application the first time, I already have `reincarnationNumber` value equal to **3**.

In other words, I have this info displayed in browser:

```
ViewScoped bean reincarnation is 3
ViewScoped bean access counter is 1
```

Why is that?
**Why ViewScoped bean has bean created 3 times?**

Thanks in advance!

### **SOLUTION**

As it is stated in the comments, the cause was "start browser" checkbox checked in Run Configurations in my IntelliJ IDEA. The trick is when browser is auto-started from IDE I have viewScopedBean initialized 3 times.

Comment: Can you describe which environment (jsf version, server type) are you using? Can't recreate the problem with Tomcat 6, Mojarra 2.1.26. I get both of them `1`.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I use Tomcat 7.47 + jsf 2.2.1.  
jsf library was automatically downloaded by IDE from maven (groupId=org.glassfish; artifactId=javax.faces).
As I see, this is glassfish jsf implementation. Maybe it is the cause of the problem?

Comment: @XtremeBiker I started the same project at glassfish 4.0.
Now I recieve the value **2** for `viewScopedBean.reincarnationNumber`

Comment: It's perfectly working for me with 2.2.1 (Mojarra, which is glassfish's implementation) + Tomcat 6 (with Tomcat 7 too). BTW, your xml-DOCTYPE declaration is unecessary. Just begin your page with `html`.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I've found the source of problem. Actually I had "start browser" checkbox checked in Run Configurations of my IntelliJ IDEA.
The trick is when browser is auto-started from IDE I have viewScopedBean initialized 3 times. When I simply manually launch the browser and open the page everything works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not created 3 times, just called the getter several times... and that's because... you can check this answer:

[Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)